# I don't understand what's mean that should use trident if the message process must only once

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I don't understand what's mean that **should use the trident if the message process must only once**
Can I process message only once using ack() and fail() on BaseRichSpout?
If I don't need the trident's functions(eg. groupping, jonning..), Can I use the BaseRich?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storm supports "at least once" process, as the failed message will be handled again from the beginning, which will cause some repetition.

Trident is one way to support "exactly once" process.

So if you have to handle messages only once in storm ,you have to use trident.